# When is the parent/presenting view controller set on a modal view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, view

I am presenting a modal view controller. In that modal view controller's `viewDidLoad`, I can't seem to find any reference to the parent VC.... `parentViewController`, `presentingViewController`, etc. If this isn't set yet, how am I supposed to get a reference to it?

Comment: In short, I've found that `presentingViewController` works (in storyboards, at least) if the first view controller is not embedded in a navigation controller, but if it is, you get the navigation controller. You can play games to try to figure out the logical presenting view controller, but I think it's just much better to have your own property in your presented view controller that the presenting view controller sets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a general solution, you could have your own property in the second controller which is a `weak` pointer to the first view controller. The first controller should set the second controller's property in the first segue's `prepareForSegue`.

In answer to your question, `parentViewController` is only set when using view controller containment (which you're not doing). The `presentingViewController` is set when you do `presentViewController`, but the behavior changes depending upon whether the first view controller is embedded in a navigation controller or not (if it is embedded, the second view controller's `presentingViewController` is the navigation controller, if not, it is the view controller you'd expect it to be). And it appears that `presentingViewController` is not set at all if you do `pushViewController`.

Bottom line, I find it to be far more reliable and consistent if you set a custom property of the second controller during the `prepareForSegue` in the first controller.

---

So, in the `SecondViewController`, I have a .h `@interface` that looks like:

```
@class FirstViewController;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) FirstViewController *firstViewController;

@end
```

And then in the first view controller, I have a `prepareForSegue` that looks like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"IdentifierForSegueToSecondControllerHere"])
    {
        SecondViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.firstViewController = self;
    }
}
```

Obviously, that above point applies if you're using storyboards. If you're using NIBs, you would do something like:

```
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
controller.firstViewController = self;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Anyway, once you've set that `firstViewController` property in your `SecondViewController`, that `SecondViewController` can now access properties or invoke public methods of the `FirstViewController`, such as:

```
// up at the top, where you have your import statements, include the following

#import "FirstViewController.h"

// then, in the @implementation of the SecondViewController, you can reference
// the first view controller and its properties, such as:

self.firstViewController.someStringProperty = @"some value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually speaking, a view can be loaded at anytime.  Just because your view has been loaded doesn't necessarily mean that it's about to be displayed in some form.

The earliest point at which you can discover your presenting view controller is in the `viewWillAppear:` method of `UIViewController`.