# How to unwind to the right view controller if current one is presented AND pushed?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, unwind-segue

I have a viewcontroller, let's say A, that is reached by three other view controllers, let's say B, C and D.

B presents `UIViewController` A modally.

C and D are part of a `UINavigationController` and thus, push view controller A.

If all of them had modal segues, I could just do a `switch(presentingViewController)` to determine who is the viewcontroller I should `unwind` to. The problem is that since two of them are in a navigation stack (B and C), they will never be a `presentingViewController`.

How do I solve this conundrum?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard and segues? If so then all you need to do is implement the same unwind method name in each view controller and the unwind segue will determine at runtime where it needs to go; see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591-CH1-DETDEST

Answer (score 0):

Check if a navigation controller exists in `A`. If it does you'd `pop`, if it doesn't you'd `dismiss`.

Comment: I need to do some custom logic depending on which one I am unwinding to. Therefore, only popping/dismissing is not enough

Comment: Sounds like `A` is doing too much then. You could have a delegate that fires on `A`'s `viewWillDisappear` that `B`, `C`, and `D` listen to. Without knowing your entire logic its hard to say.

Comment: Do you think the delegation pattern of this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898324/when-is-the-parent-presenting-view-controller-set-on-a-modal-view-controller) would be better or yours?

Comment: Writing same code in prepareSegue functions of all the parent controllers would be redundant. Delegate sounds like a better solution here. If one line is all it takes in both the cases, I don't think it matters anyways.